# Does a space have dimension at most 1 if it contains no plane?

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $X$ be a separable metric space.  Suppose that $X$ contains no subspace homeomorphic to the plane. Is it necessarily true that the dimension of $X$ is $\leq 1$?

Comment: What definition of dimension?

Comment: From Wikipedia on [Inductive dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension), it seems that for a separable metrizable space, the three most popular definitions of dimension coincide. So presumably we can use Lebesgue covering dimension, or small inductive dimension, or large inductive dimension to answer the question.

Comment: Spaces need not be locally Euclidean at all. That's why there is a general dimension definition.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are totally disconnected separable metric spaces of any dimension $n$ (even $\infty$). And totally disconnected spaces do not contain any connected subspace except singletons...